# Fragments issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I really need to understand the fragment issue.

What I just wanted to is putting my activity into a fragment or the same functionality into a fragment.

Is it possible?

I have ViewPager and fragments. And I want to display one activity in a fragment in a viewpager.

Answer (score 1):

I think you take the problem in the wrong way.

- Fragment are not similar to activities.
- Fragment is "`equivalent`" of your view.
- FragmentActivity display `XML` with `setContentView`. This `xml` will
  contains one or more Fragment.
- Each Fragment will be in charge of a part of the UI like `ActionBar`
  or anything you want.

So first thing is to create a Fragment wich creates your view. 
`Copy/paste` your code relative to this `UI` (textbox, onclick...) in your new fragment.
Then, add your fragment to your `main XMl`. 
It will works fine.

Moreover, for `viewpager` you can find a lot of tutorial on internet, but you have to understand the difference between activities and fragments.

Hope it helps.

Comment: for instance; am i able to do three tabbed viewpager, and in each fragment different webview and its control is available? like play store app